# Wix 3.8: Installer not uninstalling previous version or installing new version

Tags: windows-services, wix

I have created a Wix installer that is meant to replace an installer that was created in Visual Studio, and is supposed to update a previous version of the software it is installing.  I kept the same upgrade code that was used in the previous installer for mine, so I thought that this code would work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*"
         Name="Product"
         Language="1033"
         Version="1.0.6.0"
         Manufacturer="Company"
         UpgradeCode="PREVIOUSLY-USED-UPGRADE-CODE">
    <Package InstallerVersion="301"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine"
             Manufacturer="Company"
             Description="Installs Product"
             Keywords="Installer,MSI" />
    <Media Id="1"
           Cabinet = "Product.cab"
           EmbedCab = "yes"/>

    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of Product is already installed." AllowDowngrades="no"/>

    <Directory Id ="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name ="Company">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Product" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id ="ProductFeature"
             Title = "Product Feature"
             Level = "1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
    </Feature>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLDIR">

      <Component Id="cmpCOMAdminW2K" Guid="*">
        <File Id="COMAdminW2K" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="Interop.COMAdminW2K.dll" Source="Local\Path\To\Interop.COMAdminW2K.dll" />

      <!-- Several registry entry updates -->
      </Component>

      <Component Id="cmpCustomSerializer" Guid="*">
        <File Id="CustomSerializer" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="AREANAME.Serialization.CustomSerializer.v2.0.dll" Source="Local\Path\To\AREANAME.Serialization.CustomSerializer.v2.0.dll" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="cmpProductServer" Guid="*">
        <File Id="ProductServer" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="AREANAME.ProductServer.Shared.v2.0.dll" Source="Local\Path\To\AREANAME.ProductServer.Shared.v2.0.dll" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="cmpRemotingHelper" Guid="*">
        <File Id="RemotingHelper" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="AREANAME.TechPC.RemotingHelper.v2.0.dll" Source="Local\Path\To\ND1.TechPC.RemotingHelper.v2.0.dll" />
      </Component>

      <Component Id="cmpProduct" Guid="*">
        <File Id="Product" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="AREANAME.TechPC.Service.Product.v2.0.exe" Source="Local\Path\To\AREANAME.TechPC.Service.Product.v2.0.exe" />
        <ServiceInstall
          Id="Product"
          Name="ServiceName"
          DisplayName="Full Service Name"
          Start="auto"
          ErrorControl="normal"
          Type="ownProcess"/>

        <ServiceControl
          Id="startAndStopUsrPres"
          Name="ServiceName"
          Start="install"
          Stop="both"
          Remove="uninstall"
          Wait="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="cmpProductConfig" Guid="*">
        <File Id="ProductConfig" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" Name="AREANAME.TechPC.Service.Product.v2.0.exe.config" Source="Local\Path\To\AREANAME.TechPC.Service.Product.v2.0.exe.config" />
        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveProductConfig" Name="AREANAME.TechPC.Service.Product.v2.0.exe.config" On ="install"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="VersionRegistryEntry" Guid="*">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software">

          <RegistryKey Key="Company"
                       ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">

            <RegistryKey Key="Product"
                         ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">

              <RegistryValue Id="ProductVersionEntry"
               KeyPath ="yes"
               Action ="write"
               Name="Version"
               Value="1.0.6.0"
               Type="string"/>

            </RegistryKey>
          </RegistryKey>
        </RegistryKey>

      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

*Above code is obviously redacted.

The installer will be run on almost all of my company's machines through a software management system, so I have been testing my installer with the following command line:

```
msiexec.exe /i <ProductInstaller>.msi /quiet /l*v log.txt
```

That brings me to **the problem.**  Some of you may have noticed that I have a "RemoveFile" tag inside the component containing my config file.  I have it there because that file was not always getting updated when the installer ran.  This, coupled with the MajorUpgrade schedule, allowed me to remove that file out of the target directory and ensure that the new config file was always getting put in that location.  That fix seemed to work in my tests.  The program files all appeared to be correct whenever I tried to run the installer on a machine that had a previous version of the program.  However, even with all of the correct files in the correct location, the service would not start, either automatically or by manually attempting to start it within services.msc.  Additionally, whenever I tried to run the following to uninstall:

```
msiexec.exe /x <ProductInstaller>.msi /quiet /l*v log.txt
```

I received the error message "This action is only available for products that are currently installed."

I'm not sure what to make of that since the new files are where they are supposed to be, and the old files are gone.

With all of that information, my question is somewhat vague: **"What am I missing in order to have an installer that puts all files in the proper location and starts the service on install, and stops the service and removes the files on uninstall?"**

Any assistance would be appreciated, and I would be happy to provide portions of the log files upon request to anybody who thinks that they would help in helping me to figure out what's going on.

Thank you!
-Seth

Comment: Well, I think I discovered why the service wouldn't start.  Somehow, one of my assemblies that the main dll depends on got renamed after installation.  That solves that error.  We'll see if any other problems remain once I get that solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, in fact, that renamed .dll that was causing the problem.